# Regular expression matches a few symbols but not includes some

Tags: python, regex

There is paragraph, and I want to use regular expression to extract all the words inside.

```
a bdag agasg it's the cookies for dogs',don't you think so? the word 'wow' in english means.you hey b 097  dag final
```

I have tried several regexes with re.findall(regX,str), and found one that can match most words.

```
regX = "[ ,\.\?]?([a-z]+'?[a-z]?)[ ,\.\?]?"
```

['a', 'bdag', 'agasg', "it's", 'the', 'cookies', 'for', "dogs'", "don't", 'you', 'think', 'so', 'the', 'word', "**wow'**", 'in', 'english', 'means', 'you', 'hey', 'b', 'dag', 'final']

All are good except `**wow'**`.

I wonder if regular expression could explain the logic "it can be a comma/space/period/etc but can't be an apostrophe".

Can someone advise?

Comment: Try `r"[ ,.?]?\b(?!wow\b)([a-z]+'?[a-z]?)[ .?]?"`

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? The regex should match words with apostrophes in the middle like `don't`, and also those with apostrophes at the end like `dogs'`, but not those, where the apostrophes are used as quotes? And what if the quote consists of more than one word: `so the word 'bow wow' in english`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[ ,\.\?']?([a-z]*('\w)?)[\' ,\.\?]?
```

Added another group so you'll have to select only group 1.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand what you wanted the output to be but,
try this:

```
[ ,\.\?]?(["-']?+[a-z]+["-']?[a-z]?)[ ,\.\?]?
```

using this regex lets you get the `'` and `"` within the text.

if this still was not what you wanted please let me know so I can update my answer.